# Стилистика. Правильное построение предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно построить предложение:

> До конца 5 августа жара.

Правильно ли построено это предложение?

Или же правильнее будет сказать:

> До 5 августа жара

либо

> До конца августа жара.

Возможно ли, что все три варианта правильны?

Comment: Что Вы хотите  сказать? 5 августа и конец августа — разный смысл.

Comment: Определитесь со временем: была жара или она ожидается до названного момента.

Answer (score 2):

Формально все три варианта правильны, но у них разный смысл:

- "*До конца 5 августа жара*" — формально эта фраза означает, что жара продержится до окончания 5 августа, т.е. до наступления ночи, а 6 августа жары уже не будет. Фраза неуклюжая.
- "*до 5 августа жара*" — жара продержится до 5 августа, а потом жары не будет. Уйдет жара днем 5 августа, утром или ближе к вечеру — неизвестно.
- "*до конца августа жара*" — весь август будет жарким, но в последних числах августа, а может быть даже 1 сентября жары уже не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Точный прогноз даётся ГМЦ и МЧС в виде графика. Словами изложенный прогноз достаточно информативен и полезен, если будет краток, без подробностей, в которых легко ещё и усомниться. Уместней было бы не упоминать дня и времени суток:

*Жаркая погода сохранится до первых дней августа*; *Жарко будет ещё и в начале августа*; *Жара не покинет город и в первую рабочую неделю августа*; *Жара покинет город только после первой недели августа*.

Варианты с указанием дня: *Жара продлится вплоть до 5 августа*; *В понедельник 6 августа жара сменится прохладой*.